# How to fix: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to double[]

Tags: java, android, generics, classcastexception

I encountered a problem when I tried to run the following code:

When I trying to get item from `ArrayList<double[]> list` but it throws `ClassCastException`

Method `list.get(i)` also throws excexption

```
public void drawRoutes(ArrayList<String> routes) {
    if (routes.isEmpty()) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        ArrayList<double[]> list = TransportRoutes.getRoutes(tag, routes).get(i);
        for (double[] points : list) {  // throws ClassCastException
            map.addPolyline(polylineOptions
                    .add(new LatLng(points[0], points[1]))
                    .color(color)
                    .width(POLY_LINE_WIDTH));
        }
    }
}
```

method getRoutes() :

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>> getRoutes(String tag, ArrayList<String> numbers) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<double[]>> routes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String number : numbers) {
        routes.add(sRoutesHashMap.get(tag).get(number));
    }
    return routes;
}


// sRoutesHashMap is a HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<double[]>>>
// and taken from this method


    protected static <T> T getSmth(Context context, String url) {
    T data = null;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(context);
    String json;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        json = jsonParser.execute(url).get();
        if (json != null) {
            data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<T>() {});
        } else return null;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}
```

Full stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to double[]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to double[]
            at in.transee.transee.Drawer.drawRoutes(Drawer.java:46)
            at in.transee.transee.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:45)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I used this method everythink worked:

```
public static void getAllRoutes(Context context) {
    String routesJson = sSPData.getString(sCity + ROUTES, EMPTY);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            routesJson = jsonParser.execute(URL + sCity + SEPARATOR + ROUTES).get().get(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        sRoutesHashMap = mapper.readValue(routesJson,
                new TypeReference<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<double[]>>>>() {});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which package is `ObjectMapper` from?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relationship between sRoutesHashMap and the method getSmth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are getting heap pollution <sup>†</sup>. The good news is I think you can get round it really easily by doing.

```
protected static <T> T getSmth(TypeReference<T> typeRef, Context context, String url) {
  ...
  data = mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
```

And calling it with:

```
sRoutesHashMap = getSmth(new TypeReference<HashMapOfBlahBlahBlah>(){}, context, url);
```

#### Why heap pollution?

- `mapper.readValue` either returns `Object`, or it returns `T` but is marked with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` (I couldn't work out which, probably the latter)
- you store the return as your generic type (bingo, here's your heap pollution)
- but in the generic method the `Object` returned from `mapper.readValue` isn't actually of your generic type
- and this only manifests itself later with your `ClassCastException`

Note: *anywhere you see `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` either on your generic code or on library generic code you should be careful as this outcome is likely*

#### How heap pollution?

The cause is probably because the anonymous `new TypeReference<T>(){}` in your generic `getSmth` method can't evaluate the type `T` as your concrete type argument. If you look at the source code for `TypeReference` this seems to make sense due to the way it uses `getGenericSuperclass` and `getActualTypeArguments`.

A solution would be to create your parameterized type of `TypeReference` outside `getSmth` and pass it as an argument into the method.

#### Test for heap pollution?

If I run this test program, you can probably see what I mean, and doing this on your environment will confirm it all:

```
static TypeFactory typeFactory = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestRig.<List<String>>pharaoh();                  // oh, that's bad
    TestRig.sam(new TypeReference<List<String>>(){}); // no, that's good
}
public static <T> void pharaoh() {
    TypeReference<?> typeRef = new TypeReference<T>() {};
    JavaType typeT = typeFactory.constructType(typeRef); // this is what happens inside ObjectMapper
    System.out.println("from generic  TypeReference: " + typeRef.getType().toString());
    System.out.println("from generic  TypeReference: " + typeT.toString());
}
public static <T> void sam(TypeReference<T> typeRef) {
    JavaType typeT = typeFactory.constructType(typeRef); // this is what happens inside ObjectMapper
    System.out.println("from concrete TypeReference: " + typeRef.getType().toString());
    System.out.println("from concrete TypeReference: " + typeT.toString());
}
```

results:

```
from generic  TypeReference: T <--- booooo
from generic  TypeReference: [simple type, class java.lang.Object]
from concrete TypeReference: java.util.List <--- yaaaaaay
from concrete TypeReference: [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]
```

<sup>†</sup> Ref: Java Tutorials > [Non-Reifiable Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html)

Comment: Here is the [Gist for the sample code](https://gist.github.com/AGBrown/da6a6d26ca5b48a0a380)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer!